# Resize VM to Dv2

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

Last week I had created a DsV2 VM on Microsoft Azure. I've noticed that VM costs are pretty high. After some googling, I assumed that it is because it uses [premium storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage) instead of regular one. I only want to use standard storage account, but I can't see an option to disable Premium Storage anywhere. Can you please help me to resize my VM to DV2 without Premium Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you could not resize VM from Ds series VM to D series VM. You could recreate your VM by using your VHD.**

Please refer the following steps.

1.Stop and delete your VM but don't delete the VM's VHD.

2.Create a new standard storage account and blob container in the same resource group.
Copy VHD to the new storage account, you could use Azcopy.

`AzCopy /Source:https://shuidisks446.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://shuidiag102.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:sGqtdFHQWQWYyf2tRWGF5jkeAEubTp13AVaeTM25QogxXE+K0Ezq1ulcs18qGVPhCEp6ULdLLbKVa7fMbUvYZg== /DestKey:iCjeS+eegjkSJXHjH2UqCkqXnUPiCGvxaOG0Ad2LoPgUnvBoWl9wQJtC1jc//lOj4CF7khpLQe791P4QeyTY6Q== /Pattern:shui20161222141315.vhd`

More information about Azcopy please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

3.Use the VHD to create a D series VM. It is easy for you to recreate with existing VHD by using this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet)

4.Delete your Premium Storage Account.